# how to change audio output for a specific tab without extensions or inspect element in google chrome using bookmarks

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-audio

I am on a managed chromebook and i want to watch my show while putting the kids show on the tv. I cant inspect element or install extensions. I think it may be possible with bookmarks though.

javascript:document.body.contentEditable = 'true'; document.designMode='on'; void 0

This bit of code allows me to edit the text on any site when i add it to my bookmarks and click it so i´m wondering if its possible to change audio output for a tab from a bookmark using the code that this site uses https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/multi/

Comment: With audio output, you mean the volume? If so, then what should the volume be?

Comment: Sorry I meant output device. I want one tab to play on the TV and another to play on my headphones

Comment: Ah I see. I'm afraid that's not something that your browser can solve, nor is there a JavaScript API that has that kind of access to the output of your device.